# Cannot center the modal window from angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

It is crazy but the following code:

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDialogConfig, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'decline',
    templateUrl: './decline.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../../styles/main.css']
})
    
export class DeclineComponent {

    animal: string;
    name: string;
    config: MatDialogConfig = {
        disableClose: false,
        hasBackdrop: true,
        backdropClass: '',
        width: '250px',
        height: '',
        position: {
            top: '',
            bottom: '',
            left: '',
            right: ''
        }
    };
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

    openDialog(): void {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, this.config);
    }

}

@Component({
    selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
    template: `
        This is nothing
          `
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>) { }

}
```

does not center (horizontally and vertically) the modal window whereas **in all examples** I have seen so far, it is nicely centered. I cannot find the problem...
I have to say that I am using `'~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"`. Apart from that, I tried to center it manually by adjusting the **position object** inside config. However it does not accept something like `left: '50%-125px'`. Any good ideas, please?

Comment: We need to look at a reproduction to find and fix the problem. Can you setup minimal example?

Comment: What does your dialog look like?

Answer (score 21):

**Step 4 of Angular Material getting started.**

```
// Add this line to style.css of your app.
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEZ49.png)

Be sure that you made all steps before.

[Angular Material - Getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

P.S. It's helped me.

Answer (score 16):

You are missing the configuration for entryComponent. I was facing the same issue. Adding the Component name to **entryComponent** in AppModule solved my problem.

> Because MatDialog instantiates components at run-time, the Angular
>   compiler needs extra information to create the necessary
>   ComponentFactory for your dialog content component.
>
> For any component loaded into a dialog, you must include your
>   component class in the list of entryComponents in your NgModule
>   definition so that the Angular compiler knows to create the
>   ComponentFactory for it

Add below line of code to the **app.module.ts** file

```
entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExampleDialog]
```

And you don't really need to pass the empty position configuration for the MatDialog, unless you are setting something. This will be the second thing to try after the entryComponent solution, if it doesn't resolve the issue!

Comment: Thanks.  I'd like to add that it doesn't need to be app.module, just the module that houses where you're using the dialog (e.g. `homepage.module.ts`)

Answer (score 7):

You have to configure your dialog content via entryComponents in your app.module.ts file.

You can read about this in the docs:
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-

ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    MatDialogModule
  ],

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExampleDialogComponent
  ],

  entryComponents: [
    ExampleDialogComponent
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule() {}
```

I hope that solves your problem

Comment: The `AppModule` doesn't need braces (aka. `()`)

Answer (score 3):

**For me**, adding `align-items: center` to `.cdk-overlay-pane` **worked**.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same type of issue, my modal was showing up on the very bottom left of my page, and would not honor the height/width, etc that I was passing into the dialog.open function, nor was it showing any background, etc.

I just added

```
../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css
```

to the styles line of my `angular-cli.json` file, and it now works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Define your config as follows:

```js
config: MatDialogConfig = {
    disableClose: false,
    hasBackdrop: true,
    backdropClass: '',
    width: '250px',
    height: '',
    position: {
        top: '50vh',
        left: '50vw'
    },
    panelClass:'makeItMiddle', //Class Name that can be defined in styles.css as follows:
};
```

In styles.css file:

```js
.makeItMiddle{
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```